# Vertical Nav Bar Moving over Other Parts of Website / Remove Scroll Bar

Tags: css, web

I have two specific questions concerning my website for my class.

First, my floating left-side vertical nav bar is getting in the way of the different sections on my theme/genre page of my website.
[image]

Whenever I go to this page, the nav bar by default is pushing my first section ("Horror") over to the right.  This is good and I want ALL of my sections to permanently move to the right so that my nav bar will not be floating over any of my sections.  However, right now only this first section is moved to the right and while the nav bar "floats" down, the nav bar either floats directly over the sections or the sections just get distorted and look weird.

Here is the Theme.html page code below.  I only included the first "section" for brevity's sake.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="favicon-animated%20dice.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
</script>
<![endif]-->
<title>Rolling Solo Theme/Genre</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="rollingsolo.css" type="text/css">
<meta name="viewport"
content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="js/float-panel.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<header>
<div id="header">
<h1>Rolling Solo</h1>
<h2>"I Roll Solo"</h2>
</div>
</header>

<div id="headings">
<h1>Board Games Theme &amp; Genre</h1>
</div>    

<div id="nav" class="float-panel">
<nav class="navigation"><!--Added .navigation-->
<ul class="mainmenu"><!--Added .mainmenu-->
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="theme.html">Theme/Genre></a>
        <ul class="submenu"><!--Added .submenu-->
            <li><a href="#Horror">Horror</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Sci-Fi">Sci-Fi</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Survival">Survival</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Pirate">Pirate</a></li>
            <li><a href="#RPG">RPG/Fantasy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Space">Space</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Apocalypse">Nuclear Apocalypse</a></li>  
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="top.html">Top Solo Games of 2017</a></li>
    <li><a href="variants.html">Variants</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>

<main>
    <section id="Horror"class="sections"><h3>Horror</h3>
    <hr>
    <a href="theme/Arkham%20Horror-The%20Card%20Game(Medium).jpg"><img  src="theme/Arkham%20Horror-The%20Card%20Game(Medium).jpg" height="80" width="80" alt="arkham horror pic" class="images"></a>
    <p>Arkham Horror is a great deck building game.</p>
    <br>
    <a href="theme/Kingdom%20Death-Monster(medium).jpg"><img src="theme/Kingdom%20Death-Monster(medium).jpg" height="80" width="80" alt="kingdom death monster pic" class="images"></a>
    <p>This game was a mega-hit during its Kickstarter campaign last year.  Extremely in demand and a great buy, if you can get your hands on it.</p>
    <br>
    </section>
```

I have looked in my CSS class "sections" and tried many times to move that blue border over to the right, but still cannot do it.

Here is my CSS code below for the theme/genre's sections and navigation code:

```
.sections {border-style: ridge; /*adjusts the Theme/Genre Sections*/
       border-width: 10px;
       border-color: #1D3D94;
       padding-left: 20px;
       padding-right: 20%;
       overflow:auto;}

.images {float: left;   /*adjust the pics in the Theme/Genre Sections*/   
     padding-top: 10px;
     padding-right: 10px;}

 #nav {float: left; width: 200px; margin: 10px 0;}

/* define a fixed width for the entire menu */
.navigation {width: 190px;} 

/* reset the lists to remove bullet points and padding */
.mainmenu, .submenu {list-style: none;
                 padding: 0;
                 margin: 0;}

/* make ALL links (main and submenu) have padding and background color */
.mainmenu a {display: block;
         background-color: #CCC;
         text-decoration: none;
         padding: 10px;
         color: #000;}

/* add hover behavior */
.mainmenu a:hover {background-color: #C5C5C5;}

/* when hovering over a .mainmenu item,
display the submenu inside it.*/
.mainmenu li:hover .submenu {display: block;
                         max-height: 200px;}

/*Now, overwrite the background-color for .submenu links only.
.submenu a {background-color: #999;}

/* hover behavior for links inside .submenu */
.submenu a:hover {background-color: #666;}

/* this is the initial state of all submenus.
we set it to max-height: 0, and hide the overflowed content.*/
.submenu {overflow: auto;
      max-height: 0;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;}
```

Is there any way to *permanently* move these sections to the right out of the way of the nav bar?

Secondly, I do not want use a scroll bar function in the nested directoires but instead show ALL of my sections together when my mouse hovers over the "Theme/Genre >" heading in my nav bar.  As of now, it only shows five of the seven sub-directories before having to use a scroll bar to scroll down to see the rest. [image]

How do I remove the scroll bar and show ALL seven sub-directories?

Thanks a lot for any and all help you may give.  I do appreciate it.

Comment: Please provide the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could handle your submenu items with the css `:hover` states.

And you could place your menu and your content like this :

```
<div class="site-container">
   <nav class="menu"><!-- Your menu--></nav>
   <main><!-- Your main content--></main>
</div>
```

and add `display: flex;` on the `.site-container`.

Set the width: of your menu to `200px` for example

And the width of the main content to `calc(100% - 200px);`

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

/* This is for including the padding and the borders into the width*/
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.site-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.menu {
  width: 200px;
}

.menu ul {
  padding: 0;
  background: #C5C5C5;
  margin-top: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu nav > ul {
}

.menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
}

.menu ul li.has-child {
  background: #5B5B5B;
}

.menu ul li.has-child li {
  display: none;
  background: #8E8E8E;
}

.menu ul li.has-child:hover li{
  display: block;
}

main {
  /*Total size minus the menu size*/
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  padding: 10px;
}

main h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.theme-item {
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.theme-title {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.theme-title:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  height: 3px;
  background: black;
  top: calc(100% + 10px);
  left: 0;
}

.games-list {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.games-list .game {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

/*clearfix hack https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/*/
.games-list .game:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.games-list .game img {
  float: left;
}

.games-list .game .description {
  float: left; 
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="site-container">
  <div class="menu">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="has-child">
          <a href="#">Theme/Genre</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sci-Fi</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Survival</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pirate</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">RPG/Fantasy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Horror</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Aventure</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Top Solo Games of 2017</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Variants</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <main>
    <h1>Board Games Themes & Genre</h1>
    <div class="theme-list">
      <div class="theme-item">
        <h2 class="theme-title">Horror</h2>
        <ul class="games-list">
          <li class="game">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" />
            <p class="description">A good game</p>
          </li>
          <li class="game">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" />
            <p class="description">Another game</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="theme-item">
        <h2 class="theme-title">Sci-Fi</h2>
        <ul class="games-list">
          <li class="game">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" />
            <p class="description">A good game</p>
          </li>
          <li class="game">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" />
            <p class="description">Another game</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

You could do an improvement by fixing your **menu** at the top left of the screen with `position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 2;`, so it's always visible. And set `position: absolute; left:100%; top: 0;` on the **submenu** and `position: relative;` on its **parent li**, so the submenu will appears at the right of your menu. It will prevent the menu from doing "Yo-yo".

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

/* This is for including the padding and the borders into the width*/
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.site-container {
  position: relative;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 200px;
}

.menu ul {
  padding: 0;
  background: #C5C5C5;
  margin-top: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
}

.menu ul li.has-child {
  background: #5B5B5B;
  position: relative;
}

.menu ul li.has-child ul {
  display: none;
  background: #8E8E8E;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.menu ul li.has-child:hover ul{
  display: block;
}

main {
  padding-left: 210px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

main h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.theme-item {
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.theme-title {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.theme-title:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  height: 3px;
  background: black;
  top: calc(100% + 10px);
  left: 0;
}

.games-list {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.games-list .game {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

/*clearfix hack https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/*/
.games-list .game:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.games-list .game img {
  float: left;
}

.games-list .game .description {
  float: left; 
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="site-container">
  <div class="menu">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="has-child">
          <a href="#">Theme/Genre</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sci-Fi</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Survival</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pirate</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">RPG/Fantasy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Horror</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Aventure</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Top Solo Games of 2017</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Variants</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <main>
    <h1>Board Games Themes & Genre</h1>
    <div class="theme-list">
      <div class="theme-item">
        <h2 class="theme-title">Horror</h2>
        <ul class="games-list">
          <li class="game">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" />
            <p class="description">A good game</p>
          </li>
          <li class="game">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" />
            <p class="description">Another game</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="theme-item">
        <h2 class="theme-title">Sci-Fi</h2>
        <ul class="games-list">
          <li class="game">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" />
            <p class="description">A good game</p>
          </li>
          <li class="game">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" />
            <p class="description">Another game</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate all of the code and the detailed explanation as well.  I will try out this code on my website and see how it goes.  Thanks again!

Comment: If you need more explanations, tell me. There are a lot of other solution for your question, but i can't list them all. Just one improvement could be to fix the menu at the top left of the screen, so when you scroll down it's always visible. You juste have to add : position: fixed; top:0; left: 0; top the menu, and padding-left: 210px to the main tag (the content).

Comment: Don't forget to validate my answer if it works for you :)

Comment: Oh yes, I will "check" this answer now.  You gave me a lot to work with and I will let you know how it all turns out.  Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Hey Alex. I tried BOTH of your solutions in my web page and they work really well.  I like the second one a little better though.

Comment: However, the menu is now blocking my HEADER section and I can't see my HEADER Title on the left-hand side. Do you know how I move the top of the Nav Bar lower so that it will be even with my "Board Games Theme&Genre" heading? Also, the sub-menu links do not work.  Example: I click on "Sci-Fi" but I do not got to the "Sci-Fi" section.  Do you have an idea how to fix this?  Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Yes, on the menu, set the property top to be be equal of your header height:  IF you header as height:80px for example, set the top property at 80px, it will do the job

Comment: Yes, that totally did it! One more question is that my sub menu links are not taking me to the Theme/Genre sections. For example, from index.html (Home page) I click on "Sci-Fi" in the sub menu, and nothing happens.  I see this in my address bar: "/index.html#"  Same thing when on theme.html page and click on a section, "/theme.html#".  Do you know why it is not going to the different theme/genre sections from ANY of my pages?

Comment: Because if you took the html that i give you, I put <a href="#">Link</a>. So it's only adding a "#" to your URL. You need to replace it by your own link. If the link aimed a container on the same page, replace href="#" by href="#container". It it's on an another page you will need to replace by href="otherpage.html"

Answer (score 0):

## Use padding-left

Make sure the items that are listed are sitting in a 'container' so that all the children inside the container can sit wherever the parent sits. This allows you to use the following CSS rules for content (with the id of #content for example):

```
#content {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 5em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
}
```

### Explanation

- `position: relative` - make sure the children abide by the basic rules of the parent
- `padding-left: 5em` - Push the parent (content) to the right of the menu by 5em, all children will be relative to the parent
- `box-sizing: border-box` - keep all the padding relative to the inside the width and height of the container (by subtracting the size) rather than appending size dynamically.
- `width: 100%` - Let the container fill the rest of the space (1)

1) if width: 100% is over-taking the space of the menu then consider using `width: calc(100% - 5em)` where 5em is the width of the menu

**Note** It's worth putting into consideration that to do this you normally need a fixed/max-width menu and would be ideal to do so. Otherwise text, images and so on may expand the menu infinitely within a percentage of that space.

#### element:hover

To eliminate the scrollbar on the menu you will have to find what is taking up the space. If these are more items that you want to show/hide when the cursor is above the menu item you can use the element selector :hover which can tell the menu to hide certain items. You can then use it to set before the hover event occurs and during the hover event. For example:

```
body { background: white; }
body:hover {background: red;}
```

A more relative example would be to set the height of the main menu item so that the rest cannot be shown (with the use of `overflow: hidden`)

```
ul li ul li {display: none};
ul li:hover ul li {display: block}
```

Comment: I appreciate the detailed explanation to my question. I will try out your suggestions on my website and see how it goes. Thanks again!